# Honda Civic Hybrid 2010 oil life indicator

Tags: honda, civic, hybrid

I'm unable to see the Oil Life percentage of a Honda Civic Hybrid 2010 (UK model) in the display although I followed correct instructions.

I saw following instructions to see oil life of a Honda Civic 8th gen model,

> 1. Turn the ignition switch to the ON (II) position
> 2. If the engine oil life is not displayed press the SEL/RESET knob in the instrument panel repeatedly until it is

And also I've seen many YouTube videos that doing the above steps and successfully gets the Oil Life percentage in the display.

But whenever I press SEL/RESET it loops between  Trip A, Trip B, Outside temperature and Total Mileage. Other than these 4 options I don't see anything else?

What could be the reason?

Comment: If it doesn't show up, I'd suggest your display doesn't have this feature, but that is a guess on my part.